# Enable VLAN Spanning with Python API

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to make a REST api call via the SoftLayer Python API to enable VLAN spanning for an account. I found the [following link](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/setVlanSpan) and I am trying to adapt its contents into what I think the call would look like, what I have so far:

```
url = 'https://' + username + ':' + api_key +'@api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/' + account_id  + '/setVlanSpan.json'
data = '{"parameters":[[{"enabled": "True"}]]}'
response = requests.post(url, data=data)
```

My question beyond that is where/how to get the `account_id` in order to feed that to the URL in the post request? If there is a better way to accomplish this task with the python API, then that works too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to specify the accountId for  [SoftLayer_Account::setVlanSpan](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/setVlanSpan) method.

Try the following change in your code:

```
url = 'https://' + username + ':' + api_key +'@api.service.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/setVlanSpan.json'
data = '{"parameters":["True"]}'
```

Anyway, you can get the accountId with the following rest request:

```
https://$username:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getObject

Method: Get
```

The "id" property from the response refers to accountId.

Some references:
http://sldn.softlayer.com/article/Python

Comment: Thank you for the help! Worked perfectly and the added accountId will surely help in the future.